# How to redirect to a mobile template in SMARTY

Tags: templates, mobile, smarty

Hoping you guys can help me out here.

I am using the FSRevolution incentive script (fsrevolution.com), which is all encoded other than the smarty template files.

I'm looking to create a mobile template, and was wondering if I can redirect users to a mobile template within the SMARTY file system? So basically when a user visits the site on their mobile, it will switch to the mobile template.

Could this be done solely within the SMARTY files, or would I need access to the other encoded script files to modify?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using the RegEx from [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) you could easily write a plugin:

```
<?php
function smarty_function_detectMobile($params, $template) {
    $template->smarty->assignGlobal('_is_mobile', 
        preg_match('/android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4));
    );
}
```

place this file in the plugins_dir of your smarty setup. You should then be able to call it within your template:

```
{detectMobile}
{if $_is_mobile}
  something for a mobile device
{else}
  something for desktops
{/if}
```

I don't know fsrevolution and I don't know how they encoded their scripts. If it doesn't work, you may want to contact them in order to introduce your own smarty plugins.

The above plugin is meant for Smarty3, if fsrevolution is using Smarty2, change the line

```
$template->smarty->assignGlobal('_is_mobile',
```

to

```
$template->assign('_is_mobile',
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rodney. Seem to be getting a plugin error when I execute this - do the plugins need some kind of installation or should smarty pick them up automatically?

Comment: Just to add - the error I'm getting is: unrecognized tag 'detectMobile' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 590)

Comment: I don't know how fsrevolution configured the smarty integration. Normally you can drop a plugin `smarty_function_foobar()` into the file `function.foobar.php` in the plugins directory. If that doesn't work, you may want to contact fsrevolution for support.

Comment: Of course you don't see `function.foobar.php` in your plugins directory. I was just pointing out how you have to name your file containing the plugin and where to put it!

Answer (score 0):

It's ok for me,

I have replace $useragent by $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] in function

And file name is : function.detectMobile.php

directory : smarty/plugins/